# Get Audio Levels of Music Playing

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, audio

I'd like to create some sort of visualization in my app that uses the music that's already playing in on the device (iPhone or iPad). Is it possible to get the audio data that is being played by other apps, such as the default music app, or even something (third party) like Spotify?

Basically, I just want my UI to react to the music playing, but I'd rather not force the user to use my music player for the UI to react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Sorry.

Comment: Hmm, too bad. I get why, for security reasons, but the app I'm considering isn't music-centric enough to have its own music player-- it would have simply been for the visuals.

Comment: It isn't directly down to Apple forbidding it. It is more todo with the way the System works. Ok you could say they are the same thing. Even todo this on OSX you have to install fake audio drivers at the kernel level and change your System audio in and outs - this is just not possible on iOS. You could monitor the input from the microphone. Wouldn't be any good if the user was wearing headphones, but maybe it could be more of a sound levels monitor app instead of a music visualizer.